# Why does parsing a dict very occasionally take far longer than usual

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization

Whilst working on a fairly large Python(3) project I have encountered this strange behaviour where iterating through a dictionary will very occasionally (<0.1% of the times) take thousands of times longer than normal.

Here is a very minimal example that displays the behaviour:

```
    from time import perf_counter
    from statistics import mean

    d = {"1": 0}
    times = []

    for _ in range(1000000):
        start = perf_counter()
        d = {k: v for k, v in d.items()}
        diff = (perf_counter() - start) * 10e6
        if diff > 0:
           times.append(diff)

    print("Mean: {}".format(mean(times)))
    print("Max: {}".format(max(times)))
```

Eg. running this once gives me a mean time of 10.806199298240244 microseconds, but a max time of 31015.980057418346 microseconds, about 3000 times longer than normal.

Is there a way I can avoid this behaviour or is it inherent to Python?

Edit: Timed using perf_counter() instead of datetime

Comment: FWIW, I can't say whether or not this phenomena is real -- However, using `datetime.now()` for timing something (particularly something this small) is likely to be highly inaccurate.  `timeit.default_timer` is likely to be a much better place to start understanding this phenomena...

Comment: Try disabling garbage collection for the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the dictionary creation actions you committed took only a few nanoseconds - and had been treated as `0` microseconds. As a result, every action that had some delay, even if the delay was for a few microseconds, counts as a huge change - and every `0` result lowers the average out of its bounds.

Also, the maximum results are **highly** distinct from the rest (they are usually due to CPU stuff) - using deviation can show the difference clearly, and mark the general range of the normal results.

---

Try

```
from time import perf_counter
from statistics import mean, stdev

d = {"1": 0}
times = []

for _ in range(100000):
    start = perf_counter()
    d = {k: v for k, v in d.items()}
    diff = (perf_counter() - start) * 10e6
    if diff > 0:
        times.append(diff)

print("Mean: {}".format(mean(times)))
print("Stddev: {}".format(stdev(times)))
print("Max: {}".format(max(times)))
```

and you should get less extreme differences - and much smaller results than using `time.time` or `datetime.now` (also, take a look at the standard deviation):

```
Mean: 11.520527719010078
Stddev: 4.476865528640042
Max: 443.1869339160954
```

Comment: `time.perf_counter` or `timeit.default_timer` should probably be used instead of `time.time`.  Also, It's probably a good idea to use `timeit` to do the whole thing as it handles oft-forgot details like turning off the garbage collector (which is quite possibly the culprit for the few long cycles here).  Unfortunatly, I'm not aware of a way for it to give you a histogram of the actual results...

Comment: @mgilson I believe matplotlib could

Comment: @mgilson changed to `perf_counter` - results are more accurate and much smaller. thanks!

Comment: Doing this still gives me a mean of 12.971177314323826 and a max of 10578.632354736328, so still a thousand times longer in the worst case than on average. I agree that most of the time the operations are so quick that the timing would be inaccurate, it's just the random occasions that take far longer that I need to understand.

Comment: Actually, even when using your code and doing a million tests you still get the same behaviour, eg. Mean: 11.52598847169429 Max: 39204.430067911744

Comment: @Mrid added stddev to show how irregular the maximum is (hint: **very**)

Comment: @UrielEli That's what I'm trying to understand, why in these very rare cases does this operation take thousands of times longer than normal? In the project I am working on this function gets called over a million times and as a result these cases come up regularly.

Comment: @Mrid `sum(1 for x in times if x > 40)` returns `15` to `20`. That means `20` slow cases (where slow is `40` **micro** seconds and up) per `100000`, or `1` slow cases per `5000`.